# upgrade ubuntu packages and kernel without any user interaction

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, package-management

```
#!/bin/bash

### change from Static IP to DHCP
H=$(date +%H)
if (( 11 <= 10#$H && 10#$H < 18 )); then
echo -e  "network:\n  version: 2\n  renderer: NetworkManager\n  ethernets:\n   enp0s3:\n    dhcp4: yes" > /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
sudo netplan apply

### create the log file 
var=$(ip a | grep -A 3 ens33 | grep "inet " | cut -d " " -f 6) 
echo DHCP IP= $var > logfile
echo ########################################

### update and upgrade packages without user interaction
sudo apt-get update && apt-get --yes --force-yes upgrade > tmp.txt

### add the lists to the log file
echo "packages that were updated" >> logfile
awk '/^the following/{p=0} /NEW packages will be installed/{p=1} p' tmp.txt >> logfile
echo ########################################
echo "packages being cleaned" >> logfile
awk '/^the following/{p=0} /packages were automatically installed and are no longer required/{p=1} p' tmp.txt >> logfile
echo ########################################
### remove the not required packages
sudo apt autoremove

### chcek if reboot needed or not
cat tmp.txt | grep -A 20 "the following NEW packages will be installed:" |grep "grub-common-*" > tmp2.txt
cat tmp.txt | grep -A 20 "the following NEW packages will be installed:" |grep "grub-pc-*" >> tmp2.txt
cat tmp.txt | grep -A 20 "the following NEW packages will be installed:" |grep "linx-image-*" >> tmp2.txt
cat tmp.txt | grep -A 20 "the following NEW packages will be installed:" |grep "linux-headers-*" >> tmp2.txt

if [ -s tmp2.txt ]
then
    echo "there's kernel/grub update happened" >> logfile
    echo ########################################
    reboot
else
    echo "there's no kernel/grub update happened" >> logfile
    echo ########################################
fi

### clean the tmp file
rm -f tmp.txt tmp2.txt
 
### last reboot time
uptime=$(uptime -s)
echo last reboot time= $uptime >> logfile
echo ########################################
fi

### back IP again to Static
echo -e  "network:\n  version: 2\n  renderer: NetworkManager\n  ethernets:\n   enp0s3:\n    addresses:\n     - 192.168.100.100/24" > /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
sudo netplan apply
```

this is my code i have tried but the output is not correct, i'm not sure where's my issue

Comment: Click on EDIT button in your post and then you will see a BUTTON like {} select your sample Input_file and click on {} to wrap that up in CODE TAGS and similarly do for all examples(only for sample data not for your language please). you could use backticks too for keeping data in code tags too.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: update and upgrade packages without user interactions, create log file with all details like new pkgs installed, pkgs removed and so on, and if specific pkgs upgraded like grup or image system should reboot and these details must be logged in log file

Comment: or you can use this: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/unattended-upgrades (which is not limited to just security).

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your script. In the output apt writes "The following...", starting with a capital T. Another typo I see in `grep linx-image`. I would suggest you take a look at `apt list --upgradable` if it is available on the system. I assume its output will never be touched, because it's not an interactive command.